# teradata recursive query scenario

Tags: sql, teradata

I have an input table as below

```
Order_id    previous_order_id   ordertype_opprotunity   global_order_id
 103        102                "in progress"            11111
 102        101                "in progress             22222
 101        xx                 "new order"              33333
```

I need to check order_id and previous_order_id recursively till ordertype_opprotunity matches "new_order"  then pick the value of global_order_id.
As example in for 103 prev is 102 then again for 102 prev is 101 for 101  ordertype_opprotunity is "new order" and the value is 33333.
output will be like

```
Order_id  global_order_id
103       33333
```

Comment: it must be query or can it be stored procedure selecting the thing You want at the end?

Comment: It should be a query as we want to use it as lookup.

Comment: any help on this one please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to gte the expected result.

You might start with the "last" order and go up the chain until you find 'new order':

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
 (
   SELECT t.*, Order_id AS baseOrder_id
   FROM tab AS t
   WHERE NOT EXISTS -- last order in chain
    (
      SELECT * 
      FROM tab AS t2
      WHERE t.Order_id = t2.previous_order_id
    )

   UNION ALL

   SELECT t.*, cte.baseOrder_id
   FROM tab AS t
   JOIN cte 
     ON t.Order_id = cte.previous_order_id 
   WHERE cte.ordertype_opprotunity <> 'new order' -- stop when the previous recursion was a "new order"
 )
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE ordertype_opprotunity = 'new order' -- only return the "new order" type
```

Comment: Thank you dnoeth for solution and detailed explanation.

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer as the solution, @OmprakashRathi